# Link event to dependency?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I'm using TelemetryClient.TrackEvent to record file uploads within my .NET Core/C# web service, with their duration and throughput.

I'm also using DependencyTelemetry to connect together the various stages of my event handling:

```
        using var dop = TelemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("Upload file event", correlationId);
```

However I don't see a way to connect the custom event to the dependency, so it shows up in the Application Insights Performance page.  I see my request and the child dependencies, but no custom events.  It would be great to see the custom events spawned from within my dependency, all linked together.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, and now I'm getting traces linked to requests/dependencies.  Also showing how to set a custom role name on the TelemetryClient.

```
var tconfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration
        {
            InstrumentationKey = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")?["InstrumentationKey"]
        };
        tconfiguration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
        this.TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(tconfiguration);
        TelemetryClient.Context.Cloud.RoleName = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")?["RoleName"];
```